# Vuetify tooltip hover with link

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to have [Vuetify's v-tooltip](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tooltip/#api-props) with a clickable link?
At this point using the default code provided by documentation

```html
    <v-tooltip bottom>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-icon
          color="primary"
          dark
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
        >mdi-home</v-icon>
      </template>
      <a href="#">clickable link</a>
    </v-tooltip>
```

We can't click the anchor link because once we mouse out the icon, the tooltip automatically closes. Is this a limitation on Vuetify ?

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 problems to solve:

1. Tooltip hides as soon as mouse leaves the activator (the icon). Just use `close-delay` prop set to (for example) 2000 (ms) ...so the tooltip wont disappear immediately but only after 2 seconds when you move mouse out of the icon...
2. By default, Vuetify tooltip's content is rendered with the [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) CSS property. Which means the content do not generate any pointer events. Only thing you can do about it is to override the default style...

`template`

```html
     <v-tooltip bottom close-delay="2000">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <v-icon
            color="primary"
            dark
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"
          >
            mdi-home
          </v-icon>
        </template>
        <a href="#">clickable link</a>
      </v-tooltip>
```

`style`

```css
.v-tooltip__content {
  pointer-events: initial;
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/liwoj/pen/MWmqONP)

Comment: Using Nuxt I had to put this in the <style> with scoped, e.g <style scoped> & it worked, nice one!

Answer (score 0):

You can control visibility by using v-model on the tooltip.

The following is taken from vuetifys example on visibility:

```
<v-tooltip
   v-model="show"
   top
>
   <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-btn
         icon
         v-bind="attrs"
         v-on="on"
      >
         <v-icon color="grey lighten-1">
            mdi-cart
         </v-icon>
      </v-btn>
   </template>
   <span>Programmatic tooltip</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

And then define show in data:
show: false

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips/#visibility